# CodeIgniter: 2 buttons, one form, different action

Tags: php, codeigniter

so I am adding another payment type in my system. I have one form which posts the values to a controller. In that controller based on the values of the submit it would redirect to the different functions for payment. However in one case it still goes to the main action that is mentioned in the form, Kindly find the code mentioned below:

**CONTROLLER:-**

```
        if ($this->input->get_post('order_type')=="order") {
            $payment_type = $this->input->get_post('submit_btn');

            if($payment_type == "Payvision"){   
                $this->basicauth($id);          
            }
            else if($payment_type == "Sagepay"){
                $this->make_payment($id);
            }
        }
```

**VIEW:-**

```
    <?php echo form_submit('submit_btn', 'Sagepay', 'class="btn btn-success"'); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit_btn', 'Payvision', 'class="btn btn-success"'); ?>
```

The `make_payment($id)` works, it doesn't work for `basicauth($id)` It redirects to the same page. When I select the Payvision button.

Also adding the code for the basicauth function below:

```
public function basicauth($order_id = NULL){

    $this->load->model('customer_m');

    $order = $this->order_m->get($order_id);
    $customer = $this->customer_m->get($order->customer_id);


    $this->data['order_no'] = $order->order_no;
    $this->data['amount'] = $order->total;
    $this->data['currency'] = 826;
    $this->data['customer'] = $customer->name . ' ' . $customer->lname;
    $this->data['country'] = 826;

    $this->data['subview'] = 'agent/order/basicauth/PaymentRequest';
    $this->load->view('agent/_layout_main', $this->data);

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**VIEW (EDIT):-**

```
<?php echo form_open('agent/order/edit/'.$order->id,array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'name'=>'createorder')); ?>
```

Comment: Well you will have the same action (as not shown in the code you haven't provided)... So it is there that you would test the value of your submit button and then process it accordingly.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have added it below, also the controller code I added is in the edit function.

Comment: :) Actually You are doing that already... It appears this is an issue in your controller getting the correct button... You can tell I am awake :)

Comment: Okay, any solution?

Comment: I am just wondering, as it works with `$this->make_payment($id)` which sends it to sagepay. I cannot figure out what's missing

Comment: Well it's not being "Sent" as such. It appears from your code that you just drop into what ever is below in your code, which will always be the same... So no matter what button you are detecting, you are always processing the same code from then on, at a guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128509/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-david-noronha).

Comment: Hi Tim, I managed to get it working using the redirect function ie. `redirect("agent/order/basicauth/$id");` Thanks for all the help and the inspiration :)

Comment: There you go! Good stuff :) I'm glad you got it working and you are welcome!